# How magento 2 render checkbox column in admin product grid

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, massaction, column

I need to disable some checkboxes in a grid based on certain criteria but not able to figure out from where the checkbox column is rendered.

I reached the following two files after some search, but changes in these files are not reflecting on the grid.

> Magento_Ui/templates/grid/cells/multiselect.html

And

> Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\Checkbox

Comment: Please add your custom module's grid code so I will guide you how to add it

Comment: @AasimGoriya I'm trying to pick it on default magento 2 catalog product grid, not the custom grid!

Comment: ok so you need to remove any columns from product grid right ?

Comment: No, I need to disable some of the checkboxes from product grid. Once the checkbox is disabled, user cannot select those prodcuts  for massactions.
http://prntscr.com/mjewa4

Comment: ohh I see, so you should have to add custom script on your product listing page